# Multiply numbers within a string by 2

Tags: c, string

I'm writing this program which multiplies numbers within a string by 2. I think I probably did it alright (the concept) but I keep getting errors and I can't compile it. It really puzzled me and I can't figure out where are the errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char* dvostruko(char* string)
{
int temp2=0;
char* ret = string;
while(*string!='\0') {

    if(*string>='0'&&*string<='9') {
        char* p = string;
        int temp=0;
        while(*p>='0' && *p<='9') {
            temp=temp*10 + *p - '0';
            p++;
        }
        int temp3=temp*2;
        if(temp3/10 > temp/10) {

            while(temp3!=0 && p >= string ) {
                temp2=temp3%10;
                *p = '0' + temp2;
                temp3=temp3/10;
                p--;

            }
        } else {
            p--;
            while(temp3!=0 && p >= string ) {
                temp2=temp3%10;
                *p = '0' + temp2;
                temp3=temp3/10;
                p--;
            }
        }
    }
    string++;
}
return ret;
}

int main()
{
char brojevi[100]="Brojevi 123 i brojevi 223.";
dvostruko(brojevi);
printf("%s",brojevi);
return 0;
}
```

For input: "Numbers 2, 4, 75."

Output: "Numbers 4, 8, 150."

Comment: Your compiler should tell you where the errors are by giving a file name and line number.  Many compilers also give a column number and print the offending line of source code with a line under it.  Solve one error at a time, starting with the first one printed (the one at the top).  Simplify your code to a [mcve] if needed.

Comment: I cannot reproduce any errors or warnings with your code on either GCC or Clang with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. You really need to add the error message you are receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep where you stop to read a number to continue from there.
I have added `q` for that 
Your test to check the number of digit is wrong, just check if the first digit is bigger than `4` and push all char to add a char to the string. Warn, the buffer size is not checked so you can overflow it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void push(char *s) {
    char prev, cur;
    prev = ' ';
    do {
        cur = *s;
        *s = prev;
        prev = cur;
    } while (*s++ != '\0');
}

char* dvostruko(char* string)
{
    int temp2=0;
    char* ret = string;
    while(*string!='\0') {

        if(*string>='0'&&*string<='9') {
            char* p = string;
            char *q;
            int temp=0;
            int one_more = *p > '4';
            while(*p>='0' && *p<='9') {
                temp=temp*10 + *p - '0';
                p++;
            }
            q = p;
            int temp3=temp*2;
            if(one_more) {
                push(p);
                while(temp3!=0 && p >= string ) {
                    temp2=temp3%10;
                    *p = '0' + temp2;
                    temp3=temp3/10;
                    p--;

                }
            } else {
                p--;
                while(temp3!=0 && p >= string ) {
                    temp2=temp3%10;
                    *p = '0' + temp2;
                    temp3=temp3/10;
                    p--;
                }
            }
            string = q;
        }
        string++;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    char brojevi[100]="Brojevi 523 i brojevi 223.";
    dvostruko(brojevi);
    printf("%s\n",brojevi);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Brojevi 1046 i brojevi 446.
```

Comment: I add a function to add an extra space if the number need one more char to be printed.